No se muestra fuente personalizada en WordPress
He instalado una fuente personalizada en WordPress vía FTP, pero no se está visualizando correctamente.
La página en la que estoy trabajando es https://renaultsanzhispano.es/ y la ruta donde se ha instalado la fuente es /wp-content/themes/astra-child/fonts/Nouvel R/.
Aparentemente, la fuente está bien instalada, ya que accediendo a la ruta a través del explorador ésta puede ser descargada. También se muestra correctamente el código CSS en el inspector, por lo que no entiendo dónde está el problema.
En el css del tema activo he añadido el siguiente código para importar la fuente:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NouvelR';
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('https://renaultsanzhispano.es/wp-content/themes/astra-child/fonts/Nouvel R/NouvelRRegular.ttf') format('ttf');
}
    
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NouvelR';
    font-weight: lighter;
    src: url('https://renaultsanzhispano.es/wp-content/themes/astra-child/fonts/Nouvel R/NouvelRLight.ttf') format('ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'NouvelR';
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('https://renaultsanzhispano.es/wp-content/themes/astra-child/fonts/Nouvel R/NouvelRBold.ttf') format('ttf');
}

body, button, input, select, textarea, .ast-button, .ast-custom-button {
    font-family: "NouvelR, sans-serif";
}


Seguramente sea un error de formato, las fuentes tienen varios formatos, .svg, woff, ttf, etc, ya que no todos los navegadores leen el mismo formato, talvez te falta alguno de esos. Te recomiendo agregar la forma en la que encolas la fuente, por favor lee [ask] y como hacer un [example]

La cuestión es que cuando trabajé en servidor local, la fuente se estaba mostrando correctamente.

por lo general los ves en local porque la fuente está instalada. en la url del font verifica que el ftp no te haya transformado mayúsculas a minúsculas y el espacio es conveniente codificarlo como %20 o renombra la carpeta a Nouvel_R usando guión bajo. dependiendo del servidor y si hay caches o plugins o minificadores o algo en el edge ( cloudflare, aws, askimet, etc)  las url con espacios dentro de css pueden "romperse"

btw ttf es medio poco web, fijate de encontrar alternativas o usar un cdn onda https://www.cdnfonts.com/nouvel-r.font

@aloMalbarez con el CDN funcionó perfectamente... Debía ser el formato ttf como indicabas!!! Muchas gracias!
